# LAN Adapter not present in Windows 7. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-adapter

I'm trying to get my friends PC to connect to my LAN switch, which it always used to do, but now I see after a few months that there is actually no Local Area Connection (1) or Local Area Connection (2) even in his adapter tab. It's extremely strange. If I plug him into my switch it doesn't recognize anything, but his port goes green like it usually does on the rear of his PC.

Does anyone know perhaps if it's maybe his drivers for it that have vanished? Because there is no LAN adapter even listed in the Dev Manager.

If it is this issue, or another, where can I obtain the necessary files or installation for the Ethernet drivers. Also, his BIOS shows no LAN or anything either. Hopefully someone can help.

He's running windows 7, with a gigabyte card. Let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: Have you tried with another network card? Different cable? Different switch port?

Comment: Different ports, different cables, but hesitant to open up his PC since I feel there's definitely a more user friendly way of fixing this issue. Also, which tool down votes?

Comment: You have tried everything but a different card and it is still faulting. Occam's razor suggests that it is the card that is at fault especially seeing it doesn't show in the BIOS.

Comment: Also calling people "tools" isn't the best way to elicit help.

Comment: Anyone else got any suggestions?

Comment: Check if the card is visibie in the device manager. If it is missing there then presume that it is broken. If not add the status of the card (e.g. Yellow exclation mark and text missing drivers) to your post.

Answer (score 1):

The driver was not installed. I managed to find the proper Gigabyte mother board Ethernet driver from their site. I installed the Ethernet driver singularly and it now detects the switch.